# Tranform FOR EACH to FOR with Indices

Tags: excel, vba

i have the following code.

Could you help me please rewrite this code to use a FOR loop instead of a FOR EACH Loop, so that i can access to the index (e.g. i) of the loop?

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_Name").Range

For Each cell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
      do_something with cell
```

I know it shouldn't be that hard, but i really do not know much about VBA. 
Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow: You aren't asking a [good, clear, concise question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion) Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question to include the code, expected behaviour, and what is wrong... then we can try to help

Comment: [try these resources found using Google](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&client=firefox-b-ab&ei=zORVW8udJIjKwALGrL6wBA&q=excel+vba+for+next+loop&oq=excel+vba+for+next+loop&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i7i30k1j0l5j0i30k1l3.4267.5010.0.5745.5.5.0.0.0.0.209.675.1j3j1.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.4.567...0i67k1.0.eBSYEtzV_hE)

Comment: Why do you want to access the index without using ranges? What are you trying to do, as you can likely accomplish with the `For Each`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, which uses an integer loop from 1 to the count of cells in the table range;

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
With Sheet1.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
    j = .Cells.Count
    For i = 1 To j
        Debug.Print "Processing cell " & i; " of " & j,
        Debug.Print "Address: " & .Cells(i).Address,
        Debug.Print "Value: " & .Cells(i).Value
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: You should use datatype `long` to avoid overflow errors

Comment: Perhaps. I'd suggest that if you are trying to deal with more than 2^15 cells, then looping through them individually is probably not the most efficient approach, in the first place...

Comment: SO is full of those overflows... Plus, there is really no reason not to use `long` (no, it is *not* using more memory). And even if you are writing them into an array all at once for speed optimization, you will need a `long`.